# Grunt Qunit exclude file(s)

Tags: gruntjs, phantomjs, qunit, grunt-contrib-qunit

I have configured the qunit task like this:

```
//For testing
qunit: {
    all: ['Test/**/*.html']
},
```

Is it possible if I want to exclude one (or two) particular html file?. I want to do something like this:

```
//For testing
qunit: {
    all: ['Test/**/*.html'],
    options: {
         exclude: ['Test/**/ToBeExcluded.html']
    }
},
```

I read documentation of qunit, but didn't see something like this. Is there a way? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QUnit grunt task uses the same [globbing pattern](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) matcher as most other tasks. Therefore, you can simply add a negated pattern to your target array of URLs:

```
qunit: {
    all: ['Test/**/*.html', '!Test/**/ToBeExcluded.html']
}
```